# How to rename the bot using Bot Framework composer

Tags: botframework, chatbot, bot-framework-composer

How to rename the bot from Bot Framework composer?. I had tried under Configure > Overview or Bot Settings. However, I could not see any option.

I tried to rename via Microsoft Visual Studio (https://medium.com/c-sharp-progarmming/safely-rename-a-project-folder-visual-studio-f3c6bd4d0bd6). This one did rename the project, however, it did not change all the dependent files and eventually the bot failed to start with the following error message.

"Sorry, something went wrong with publishing. Try again or exit out of this task.

Sorry, root lu file 'CoreAssistantV2.en-us' does not exist"

PS: Original project/bot name was 'CoreAssistant', tried to rename to 'CoreAssistantV2'

Bot Framework composer Version: v2.1.0

Really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you have created the bot . you cant rename it. This is feature [request](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-Composer/issues/6905)

Comment: Thanks @Vinoth Rajendran for your response & link to feature request. Appreciate if you can comment on any workarounds that works.

Comment: Thank you @seelan